# Aligot's texture is off - too solid, not runny/liquid enough

Tags: substitutions, cheese, potatoes, cream

I made some [aligot](https://www.seriouseats.com/pommes-aligot-french-cheese-mashed-potatoes-recipe), which is, kinda, sorta, like a mashed potatoes fondue, minus the wine and plus... a lot of heavy cream.

boil 1.5# potatoes, rice them, add 1 cup heavy cream, work it in, lot, then 10 oz grated cheese.  Don't forget 100g butter, and garlic, it's a French dish (from the Midi region).  Real mountain shepherd's dinner kinda stuff.

The consistency should be a semi-liquid soupy mess that will stretch out from the pot when you ladle it out.  Not break, not dribble either.  Close to condensed milk, but a bit firmer.  Not quite liquid, now, but way more runny than a paste or mash potatoes.  You eat it as is, possibly with some salami or pickles or whatever.  Not bread though.

Here's the thing.  My partner is lactose intolerant and I would have balked anyway at so much cream.  So I used (lactose free) yoghurt instead.  And butter.

The taste was great.  The texture wasn't there though.  More like really soft mashed potatoes, but never quite the unctuous behavior of the real aligot.

Was the missing bit not using real heavy cream?  Finer ricing?  The texture is a big part of the attraction.

Also, don't have a ricer, so I used rather a big cheese grater, which was hell on my hands, so I might have looked the other way if bits broke off and smashed them the regular way, by spoon.

Comment: "I would have balked anyway at so much cream." what's wrong with cream?

Comment: did you get the right cheese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yogurt is very high acidity compared with cream, as well as having some enzyme and bacterial action from the culture.  Presumably you were using a low-lactose cheese as well.  And you didn't have a ricer.  Given that, I would have been shocked if the texture hadn't been different.

If you're going to try to make low-lactose aligot, you should try to match the original recipe as closely as possible, using lactose-removed cream and the proper tools.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what's missing is probably the cream, which contains a unique suspension of fat globules which doesn't occur in butter. You can't leave out the fat, or change it for a very different sort of fat, and expect the texture to be the same. It's also possible the potatoes are different; waxy potatoes are the norm in France but russetted potatoes are the norm elsewhere.

(As a rule of thumb, I avoid using a recipe I don't intend to follow. If I'm going to balk at a major aspect of the recipe, I balk at the recipe instead. I suspect that googling "low fat aligot" will lead to only disappointment, but if you want to make low fat aligot, that's the best way to find a recipe for it.)

Incidentally, yogurt and cream contain similar proportions of lactose.

Comment: it was a lactose free yoghurt.